# How can I make a Grafana template with a variable reference another variable using Prometheus as a datasource?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a Grafana dashboard with template variables for `services` and `instances`. When I select a service how can I make it filter the second template variable list based on the first?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can reference the first variable in the second variables query. I'm not certain if there is a way using the `label_values` helper though.

First variable 
query: `up`
regex: `/.*app="([^"]*).*/`

Second variable:
query: `up{app="$app"}`
regex: `/.*instance="([^"]*).*/`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

label_values works just fine using variables. For ex:

```
label_values(cassandra_keyspace_readlatency_count{product="$product"}, keyspace)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a cleaner option. Thanks @Firdousi Farozan

Answer (score -1):

****Variable 1 (get labels from metrics, ends with below):**

name: instance

label: instance

type: Query

Query: label_values({**name**=~".*jvm_JvmMetrics_MemNonHeapUsedM"}, instance)

****Variable 2 (depends on variable 1)**:

name: task_name

label: task_name

type: Query

Query: label_values({**name**=~".*jvm_JvmMetrics_MemNonHeapUsedM",instance=~"$instance"},task_name)

Symbol "~" for multiple values